# Does a Wi-Fi 300Mbps router allow you to download at max 300Mbps?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Some context for my question. I have a fiber optic connection to my home on a 300Mbps data contract. The contract includes a device that converts from optical to Ethernet. It's a gpon onu an5506-02-FG which also acts like a Wi-Fi router.

Now, the problem is that I couldn't find anywhere in this thing's specs how many Mbps it has. I couldn't get more than 50Mbps on any device (phone, laptop, tablet).

Seems I can use this device as a "bridge" (for doing just the medium conversion) and stick my own router into it. I was thinking of a 300Mbps TP-Link TL-WR841N router but the installation team said I'm going to waste my money because it will work just as worse as the gpon onu, which I don't get.

What speeds can I expect from the 300Mbps TP-Link TL-WR841N router if I do this? Will I be able to get 300Mbps or is the installation guy right and I'll be wasting my money?

Comment: You will only get 300 Mbps if every connection between PC and server will deliver 300 Mbps.

Comment: No, well, that’s what he is asking about: Is his WiFi fast enough? It isn’t, of course. Especially with Apple devices because they will only use a single spatial stream on 2.4 GHz. Which is all the WR841N does.

Comment: @DanielB Apple devices will use all the spatial streams they have on 2.4GHz. What Apple devices don't do in 2.4GHz is use 40MHz-wide channels (because it would kill Bluetooth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: **No**.

The number is more of a theoretical maximum. My car has a speedometer that goes to 120MPH. I would not want to try driving my car that fast. WiFi speeds are like that. 300Mbps is using two channels (what used to be called Multiple In, Multiple Out, or [MIMO](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005714.html)), It's using two distinct signals (you might have two external antennas) with a maximum of 150Mbps per channel.

> Multiple-Input Multiple-Output (MIMO) is a wireless technology that uses multiple transmitters and receivers to transfer more data at the same time. All wireless products with 802.11n support MIMO. The technology helps allow 802.11n to reach higher speeds than products without 802.11n.

What eats into this number?

1. Overhead - Even in Ethernet, some of your bandwidth is being used for the overhead of the protocol. [The approximate overhead of TCP/IP is about 2.8%](http://packetpushers.net/tcp-over-ip-bandwidth-overhead/). And that's just the protocol. There's more overhead involved if you're using HTTPS/SSL/TLS encryption.
2. Signal strength - If you move into another room, you're going to lose some signal. That may mean renegotiating a packet here or there. Even standing in the same room, you might lose some signal anyways. Is this 2.4gHz or 5gHz? [5gHz gets poorer penetration](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/is-5ghz-wireless-better-than-24ghz-340). Both of them are licensed for normal wireless devices (i.e. some cordless phones use them). Then there's your neighbors, who also have their own wifi, competing with you for the same radio frequencies.
3. Number of devices - Got 5 phones, 3 tablets and 2 laptops? Remember what I said about overhead. Now multiply the overhead by the number of devices and add in the radio interference...

What should you do to maximize your WiFi?

1. Turn off the router's WiFi and buy a dedicated WiFi router. You'll get whatever throughput the Ethernet supports
2. Don't be cheap. Cheaper routers tend to have worse firmware and are far less likely to get top speeds, since the processor (which is the part you care about) tends to be a slower chip, which means less throughput. You'll notice the difference on a $300 router vs the $25 TP-Link

Answer (score 0):

Even in ideal conditions (close range, no interference) the 300Mbps flavor of 802.11n only delivers a little over 200Mbps of TCP/IPv4 throughput.

If you want a good chance that your clients can get at least 300Mbps of throughput over Wi-Fi even when they're in the next room, you want to use 2- or 3-stream 802.11ac with 80MHz-wide channels (867Mbps or 1300Mbps AC). Note that your client devices (the ones that you want to get 300Mbps+ throughput) will need 2- or 3-stream 802.11ac Wi-Fi cards as well.

Answer (score -2):

The "300 MBps" is a Marketing Number, not an Engineering Number.  It will be faster than "150 MBps", which is also a Marketing Number.  The only way to confirm speeds is to try it, or read multiple independent reviews which aren't sales pitches.